# Compare DataTable list to String List

Tags: c#, excel, reflection, datatable

So I am trying to create data tables from an excel import to then be used for other things. I know the names of the spreadsheet sheets so I have created my datatables at the top of my document:

```
private DataTable Version,Pi_PROCESSPi_PMLIFEPROFILE,PIAPPLICATION,PIRUGGEDISING,ELECTRONICCOMPONENT,HFANDRFCOMPONENTS,HYBRIDANDMULTICHIPMODULE,COTSBOARDS, VARIOUSSUBASSEMBLIES,PARTCOUNT, FAMILYCOUNT;
```

I then have a list and a for loop when the spreadsheet is read that assigns the spreadhseet names to that list

```
List<string>ExcelSheets = new List<string>();
```

The excel spreadsheet list and the datatable declarations have the same name

I have a function that reads the excel spreadsheet based on the given sheet name so I want to be able to do something like (pseudo-code) :

```
foreach ExcelSheets{
Datatable = dt.ReadFunction()
}
```

With DataTable being the declared datatables at the top of the file.

So I want to say for each Sheet in the list, run the function and assign the result to the corresponding datatable

Edit: Code for reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using S = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets;
using E = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlAttribute;

namespace FidesToRWB
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }




    #region Strings
    string FileType;
    string FileDesc1;
    string FileDesc2;
    string FileQty;
    string FileID;
    string T_max;
    string NLayer;
    string NConnection;
    string NContact;
    string NAnnualCycles;
    string NumberOfPins;
    string NumberofSMD;
    string RiseofTemp;
    string PApplied;
    string VApplied;
    string VContact;
    string IContact;
    string UNormal;
    string LimitandManual;
    string NoofManov;
    string Louput;
    string NDT;
    string NST;
    string IApplied;
    string Qman;
    string Qcomponent;
    string RAMan;
    string Experiance;
    private string newLine; 
    #endregion

    private DataTable Version,Pi_PROCESSPi_PMLIFEPROFILE,PIAPPLICATION,PIRUGGEDISING,ELECTRONICCOMPONENT,HFANDRFCOMPONENTS,HYBRIDANDMULTICHIPMODULE,COTSBOARDS, VARIOUSSUBASSEMBLIES,PARTCOUNT, FAMILYCOUNT; 

    List<string>ExcelSheets = new List<string>();


    List<string> phases = new List<string>();



    GetDataFromExcel dt = new GetDataFromExcel();
    int ColIndex = 0;
    int start = 0;


    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileBox();
    }





    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the file based on the selected grid view. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        //Need to check if the combo box is empty first - otherwise we will get an error...
        if (cmbSheetSelect.SelectedIndex <= -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a sheet to display", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            string Sheet = cmbSheetSelect.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string TrimmedSheet = Sheet.TrimEnd();

            //Enter the start row number in Excel of the data

            if (TrimmedSheet == "Pi_PROCESS&Pi_PM&LIFE PROFILE")
                {
                    start = 18;
                    ColIndex = 16;
                }

            if (TrimmedSheet == "PI APPLICATION")
                {
                    start = 9;
                    ColIndex = 4;
                }
            if (TrimmedSheet == "PI RUGGEDISING")
            {
                start = 9;
            }
            if (TrimmedSheet == "ELECTRONIC COMPONENT" || TrimmedSheet == "HF AND RF COMPONENTS" || TrimmedSheet == "HYBRID AND MULTICHIP MODULE" || TrimmedSheet == "COTS BOARDS")
            {
                start = 70;
                ColIndex = 5;



            }
            if (TrimmedSheet == "VARIOUS SUBASSEMBLIES")
            {

                start = 70;
            }



            foreach (var sheetName in ExcelSheets)
            {
                var prop = Form1.GetType().GetField(sheetName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                prop.SetValue(this, dt.ExtractExcelSheetValuesToDataTable(txtFileLocation.Text, Sheet, start, ColIndex));
            }



            //DataTable t = dt.ExtractExcelSheetValuesToDataTable(txtFileLocation.Text, Sheet, start, ColIndex);
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = t;





        }
    }




  /// <summary>
      /// Gets the sheet information
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="GetSheetInfo"></param>

    public void GetSheetInfo(string fileName)
    {
         Sheets theSheets = null;
        // Open file as read-only.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            S sheets = mySpreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets;

            WorkbookPart wbPart;
            wbPart = mySpreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
            theSheets = wbPart.Workbook.Sheets;

            foreach (Sheet item in theSheets)
            {
                cmbSheetSelect.Items.Add(item.Name);
                ExcelSheets.Add(item.Name);



            }



        }
    }

    private void txtFileLocation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileBox();
    }

    public void OpenFileBox()
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel 2007+ (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        // Insert code to read the stream here.
                        txtFileLocation.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                        cmbSheetSelect.Enabled = true;
                        btnRead.Enabled = true;
                        GetSheetInfo(txtFileLocation.Text);
                        lblPIP.Text = dt.GetCellValue(txtFileLocation.Text, "Pi_PROCESS&Pi_PM&LIFE PROFILE", "D3");
                        lblPILF.Text = dt.GetCellValue(txtFileLocation.Text, "Pi_PROCESS&Pi_PM&LIFE PROFILE", "D4");
                        lblPIRFHF.Text = dt.GetCellValue(txtFileLocation.Text, "Pi_PROCESS&Pi_PM&LIFE PROFILE", "D5");


                        int x = 20; int y = 20;

                        for (int i = 18; i < 37; i++)

                        {

                            if (dt.GetCellValue(txtFileLocation.Text, "Pi_PROCESS&Pi_PM&LIFE PROFILE", "A"+i.ToString()).ToString() != "")
                            {
                                phases.Add(dt.GetCellValue(txtFileLocation.Text, "Pi_PROCESS&Pi_PM&LIFE PROFILE", "A"+i.ToString()).ToString());

                            }



                            y += 30;

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void GenerateCSV(string fileLoc, string type)
    {
        //Strings for things.
        string csvFilePath = "C:\\RWBExport.csv";
        var csv = new StringBuilder();

        if (type == "ELECTRONIC COMPONENT")
        {

        newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3} {4}", "ID", "Category", "ParamValuesKey", "PartNumber", Environment.NewLine);
        csv.Append(newLine);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                //Type
                string Type = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                Type = Type.Substring(Type.IndexOf('[') + 1);
                Type = Type.Remove(Type.Length - 1);


                switch (Type)
                {
                    case "ECDS":
                        FileType = "FID-DS";
                        break;

                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show("Error, no matchin param value");

                        break;
                }

                //Appendix 1

                string app1 = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                app1 = app1.Substring(app1.IndexOf('[') + 1);
                app1 = app1.Remove(app1.Length - 1);

                switch (app1)
                {
                        #region Switch Case for Semiconductor Case

                    case "ECDS_01":
                        FileDesc2 = "THSSP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_02":
                        FileDesc2 = "SSSLP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_03":
                        FileDesc2 = "SMSLP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_04":
                        FileDesc2 = "THPP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_05":
                        FileDesc2 = "SSSCP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_06":
                        FileDesc2 = "SPLLP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_07":
                        FileDesc2 = "SHPSP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_08":
                        FileDesc2 = "SHSG";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_09":
                        FileDesc2 = "THM";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_37":
                        FileDesc2 = "TSSOP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_32":
                        FileDesc2 = "TSOP";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_28":
                        FileDesc2 = "SO";
                        break;
                    default:
                        FileDesc2 = "BCHIP";
                        break;

                        #endregion

                }




                //Appendix2
                string app2 = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                app2 = app2.Substring(app2.IndexOf('[') + 1);
                app2 = app2.Remove(app2.Length - 1);


                switch (app2)
                {
                        #region Switch Case for Semiconductor Type

                    case "ECDS_10":
                        FileDesc1 = "LDSD";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_11":
                        FileDesc1 = "LDRD";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_12":
                        FileDesc1 = "LDZR";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_13":
                        FileDesc1 = "LDPD";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_14":
                        FileDesc1 = "PDTH";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_15":
                        FileDesc1 = "PDRD";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_16":
                        FileDesc1 = "PDZR";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_17":
                        FileDesc1 = "PDPD";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_18":
                        FileDesc1 = "LTSJ";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_19":
                        FileDesc1 = "LTSM";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_20":
                        FileDesc1 = "LTSB";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_21":
                        FileDesc1 = "PTSB";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_22":
                        FileDesc1 = "PTSM";
                        break;
                    case "ECDS_23":
                        FileDesc1 = "PTIG";
                        break;

                        #endregion

                }

                //Qty
                FileQty = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

                //ID
                FileID = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                #region Of things you never want to repeat...add this to that list. Pulls all the variables. 

                T_max = row.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                NLayer = row.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
                NConnection = row.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
                NContact = row.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
                NAnnualCycles = row.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
                NumberOfPins = row.Cells[17].Value.ToString();
                NumberofSMD = row.Cells[18].Value.ToString();
                string numberOfDS = row.Cells[19].Value.ToString();
                RiseofTemp = row.Cells[20].Value.ToString();
                PApplied = row.Cells[21].Value.ToString();
                VApplied = row.Cells[22].Value.ToString();
                VContact = row.Cells[24].Value.ToString();
                IContact = row.Cells[25].Value.ToString();
                UNormal = row.Cells[26].Value.ToString();
                LimitandManual = row.Cells[27].Value.ToString();
                NoofManov = row.Cells[28].Value.ToString();
                Louput = row.Cells[29].Value.ToString();
                NDT = row.Cells[30].Value.ToString();
                NST = row.Cells[31].Value.ToString();
                IApplied = row.Cells[32].Value.ToString();
                Qman = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                Qcomponent = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                RAMan = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                Experiance = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();

                #endregion

                //QMAN




                string line = FileID + " " + FileType + " " + FileDesc1 + " " + FileDesc2 + " " + FileQty;

                //QUAN=1 ADJF=1 DSTYPE=LDSD DSCASE=SSSCP NINC=1 QMAN=HIGH QCOM=HIGH RMAN=VRA EFACT=RMNP PLACE=DNIF NPIN=3 TRCM=TRUSER TEMPR=20 TJA=0 POWEOP=0 STMODE=STCALC VOLT=0.5 VOLTOP=0.5 VOLTRA=1 CHSA=4 DVDC=1 RFHFPF=2.5

                var DataLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3} {4}",
                    FileID, FileType,
                    "QUAN=" + FileQty + " DSTYPE=" + FileDesc1 + " DSCASE=" + FileDesc2 + " NINC=" + numberOfDS +
                    " QMAN=" + Qman + " QCOM=" + Qcomponent + " RMAN=" + RAMan + " EFACT=" + Experiance + " NPIN=" +
                    NumberOfPins + " TRCM=TRUSER TEMPR=" + RiseofTemp
                    , "FID-" + FileID, Environment.NewLine);
                csv.Append(DataLine);

            }
            if (type == "Pi_PROCESS&Pi_PM&LIFE PROFILE")
            {


                newLine = string.Format(
                    "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21},{22},{23} {25}",
                    "AmbientTemp", "AppPollution", "CycleDuration", "DeltaTCycling", "Description", "EnvPollution", "HumanExposure", "MachineExposure", "MaxTCycling", "NetworkType", "NoCycles", "OnForPhase", "PhaseDuration", "ProductManip", "Project", "ProLevel","RandomVibs","RelHumidity","SalPollution", "SubIndex","SystemMobility","UserQual", "UserType","WeatherExposure", Environment.NewLine);
                csv.Append(newLine);
            }





        }

        File.WriteAllText(fileLoc, csv.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("File written to" + fileLoc);
    }

    private void btnGenerateImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;

        SaveFileDialog CSVGen = new SaveFileDialog();

        CSVGen.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        CSVGen.Filter = "CSV File (*.csv)|*.csv";
        CSVGen.FilterIndex = 2;
        CSVGen.RestoreDirectory = true;
        CSVGen.ShowDialog();

        string fileLoc = CSVGen.FileName;

        GenerateCSV(fileLoc, cmbSheetSelect.Text);

    }














}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Reflection to achieve this

```
foreach(var sheetName in ExcelSheets)
{
    var prop = this.GetType().GetField(sheetName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    prop.SetValue(this, dt.ReadFunction());
}
```

I had following in my Form1 Constructor and it worked for me.

```
private DataTable Version, Pi_PROCESSPi_PMLIFEPROFILE, PIAPPLICATION, PIRUGGEDISING, ELECTRONICCOMPONENT, HFANDRFCOMPONENTS, HYBRIDANDMULTICHIPMODULE, COTSBOARDS, VARIOUSSUBASSEMBLIES, PARTCOUNT, FAMILYCOUNT;

List<string> ExcelSheets = new List<string>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var list = new string[] { "Version", "Pi_PROCESSPi_PMLIFEPROFILE", "PIAPPLICATION", "PIRUGGEDISING", "ELECTRONICCOMPONENT", "HFANDRFCOMPONENTS", "HYBRIDANDMULTICHIPMODULE", "COTSBOARDS", "VARIOUSSUBASSEMBLIES", "PARTCOUNT", "FAMILYCOUNT" };
    ExcelSheets= list.ToList();
    foreach(var sheet in ExcelSheets)
    {
        var prop = this.GetType().GetField(sheet, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Debug.WriteLine(prop.FieldType);
        Debug.WriteLine(prop != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, that returns prop as a null reference?

Comment: where are your DataTable's? Is it in the same class of ExcelSheets?

Comment: Yes they are at the top of the file - there is a class that assigns them to the ExcelSheets list:


        using (SpreadsheetDocument mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
            {
                S sheets = mySpreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets;
                WorkbookPart wbPart;
                wbPart = mySpreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
                theSheets = wbPart.Workbook.Sheets;                
                foreach (Sheet item in theSheets)
                {
                    ExcelSheets.Add(item.Name);
          }
            }
        }

Comment: Try changing this.GetType() to yourClassName.GetType()

Comment: That gives

 Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType()'

Comment: Hi, when I put this under the constructor I still get the object reference not set to instance of object. I also don't use OOP to pass back to form one the code is ran from a button click